# Anylogic - Substantial variances in identical arrival rate schedule outputs

Tags: anylogic, verification

I am currently completing some verification checks on an Anylogic DES simulation model, and I have two source blocks with identical hourly arrival rate schedules, broken down into 24 x 1h blocks.

The issue I am encountering is significant differences in the number of agents generated by one block compared with another. I understand that the arrival rate is based on the poisson distribution, so there is some level of randomness in the instants of agent generation, but I would expect that the overall number generated by these two blocks should be similar, if not identical. For example, in one operating scenario one block is generating 78 agents, whilst the other is only generating 67 over the 24h period. This seems to be a common issue across all operating scenarios.

Is there a potential explanation regarding idiosyncrasies within Anylogic that might explain this?

Any pointers would be welcomed.

Comment: Have you done some longer-term tests? 24 hrs with 78 vs 67 does not sound outlandish from afar. What if you run it for a month, a week, 3 days? What if just 1 hr? Have you run it several times with different random seeds and compared? Tons of tests you can do :)

Comment: And what if both have the same rate for every 1hr block for the 24 hrs? Please share what you tested and why that is a problem (it likely isn't :) )

Comment: I am using the source blocks to generate train arrivals for Northbound and Southbound directions, and to reflect the future timetables I am testing for ideally these need to align, for example there are 5 trains per hour per direction at a peak hour. If these arent consistent this is not really reflective of the system I am trying to model. I have checked the values for each time window in my schedule, and they are the same for both source blocks. I have run the simulation for several days and one source block appears to consistently generate higher counts than the other.

Comment: And what if you delete the other source block? Does the "consistently higher" block reduce? Also, try using a custom RNG for each source block (good practice anyway). Currently, the default RNG is used for both so they influence each other subtly. ok for 95% of cases but you may be better off with custom RNGs

Comment: I will look into custom RNGs, thanks Benjamin.

Answer (score 0):

I think it occurs because it follows a poisson distribution. To solve this, you could use the interarrival time function of the source block. In that case you would have the same number of arrivals for different source blocks. However, I'm not sure whether this fits a schedule. If not, you could use the getHourOfDay() function together with a `parameter` representing the interarrival time. You then have to write the code below for every hour of the day:

```
if(getHourOfDay()==14) parameter =5;
```

Answer (score 0):

using sources with poisson distributions will definitely not produce same results... That's the magic of stocastic models.

An alternative to solve this problem is the following:

1. sources will generate using the inject function
2. use dynamic events that will be in charge to do source.inject();
3. let's imagine you have R trains coming per day, and this is a fixed value you want to use, you can then distribute the trains accross the day by doing this:

for(int i=0;i<R;i++){
create_DynamicEvent1(uniform(0,1),DAY);  //for source1
create_DynamicEvent2(uniform(0,1),DAY); //for source2
}

This doesn't follow a poisson distribution, but generates a predefined number of arrivals of trains throughout the day, and you can use another distribution of your choice if the uniform is not good enough for you.

4. run this for every day